Certificate authenthication for windows webdav client
I'm setting up a webdav server and I want to authenticate my client using client certificate.
When I'm trying to add it as a network disk on windows, I get an error
System error 59 has occurred. despite the client certificate being imported into windows.
At the same time I'm getting error 400 in my nginx log as if I used incorrect client certificate:
<my ip>- - [<date>] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 400 246 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.22631"
<my ip>- - [<date>] "PROPFIND /webdav HTTP/1.1" 400 246 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.22631"
<my ip>- - [<date>] "OPTIONS /webdav HTTP/1.1" 405 166 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.22631"

Everything works fine if I just enter server ip in Firefox if the same certificate is imported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/deprecated-features Microsoft deprecated the client side WebDAV support in Windows, so you should use a third party client like you found out, Firefox.

It's a pity to hear, however it still works fine with nextcloud for example
